# React Native setState() & Animated on Android

Tags: javascript, android, animation, react-native, setstate

I'm working on 'toast' like component for my react-native app. And it works fine with the iOS emulator, but it doesn't update the state before the animation on my android device (Galaxy Note 2). Here is the renderer of my component:

```
    render() {
        return (<Animated.View
                      style={[{transform:[{translateY: this.animatedValue}]},
                      styles.toast,
                      {backgroundColor: this.state.color}]}>
                   <Text style={styles.toastText}>{this.state.message}</Text>
                </Animated.View>);
    }
```

this.animatedValue is created like this on the constructor:

```
this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(-70);
```

And I have a show method that updates the state with `this.setState` to set the message and color, before starting the animation with `Animated.timing` I have a callback on animation end which launches a timeout to hide the toast, as I said it all works fine on iOS, but on android the first time the toast is shown it is with no text in it (I initialized `message` as an empty string) and the second time it should show it, shows the message and color of the last toast it should have shown. Ex. You do a login fail and I see on the adb console that a failed login message is being launched, still I see an empty one with green color, then I do a correct login, and I see in the adb console that a success login message is being launched, still I see the failed message with red color instead :\.

I'm figuring it can be a state change not being fully updated before the animation starts (Sometimes I've seen the toast launch with one message and in the middle/end of the animation it suddenly changed color and text), so I've first tried starting the animation on the `setState` callback, that supposedly is called after the state is fully changed and rendered the component, but I still I see the empty message toast, ironically just before the animation launch I see on my adb console the logged new state and is correctly updated, but not rendered :\ , I also tried forcing the update just after the `setState` with `this.forceUpdate` all before launching the show animation, with no success, I still get the empty message and still see the correct state in my console log :\, I even tried setting a timeout after the `setState` and `forceUpdate` to give time to the react environment to render the component or something, before the animation, but I still get the empty message and the correct state being shown on my console log D:

I know it must be something obvious or silly, but I just can't figure it out :(, I've been working with react native for like 2~3 weeks, I know javascript for a long time, and I think I get little grasp of the react native components life cycle, but nothing more, I'm still new to react native, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks xD.

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what was going on, apparently if the component is totally out of view it doesn't re-renders it (it makes sense, has nothing to render), and starts the animation on the last rendered component (that's what I think is wrong, it should re-render it as soon as it is visible again), so I patched it by making the component 1 pixel visible (1 pixel row) with transparent background, so it's re-rendered after the state update when is going to be shown and animated, and after it hides, I set it's background again to transparent, to hide the 1 pixel row, hope this helps somebody out there and I don't know where to post the issue so they get it fixed XD, good luck may the force be with you :P